# Flask Error, in Python script does not work

Tags: python, flask

unfortunately my script no longer works in Flask. I don't know how to fix this. I would be very grateful if you could help me. Here are my codes:

```py
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["uname"]
        password = request.form["passwd"]
        with open("user.txt", "r") as file:
            file.write(username + "\n" + password)

    return render_template("register.html")
```

```html
<form action="/register" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="usm"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="usm" required>
      
        <label for="pwd"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>
      
        <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'uname'
```

Comment: You can't write to a file opened in `r` "reading" mode

Comment: where is this `uname` and `passwd` in the form?

Answer (score 2):

Your form is sending a field named `usm`:

```
<input ... name="usm">
```

You're expecting a field named `uname`:

```
username = request.form["uname"]
```

The same stands for `pwd`/`passwd`.

Also, you can't `.write()` to a file opened with the `"r"` mode.